# Ceiling double two digits after point

Tags: c#, double, point, digits, ceil

I have two numbers, for example:

> 1.51 and 1.56

I need to have:

> 1.55 and 1.60

but, if it is **1.55** it just stay as **1.55**.

Comment: What you need is Math.Round() there are several specifications how to round your duoble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public double MyCeiling(double value)
{
    return Math.Ceiling(value * 20) / 20;
}
```

Usage:

```
double d1 = MyCeiling(1.51); // result 1.55
double d2 = MyCeiling(1.55); // result 1.55
double d3 = MyCeiling(1.56); // result 1.6
```

Comment: Thanks it helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
Math.Ceiling(val*20)/20
```

Comment: Thanks it helped me :)